# Accessing Active Directory with Asp.Net Identity framework without ADFS

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use the Identity Framework to connect to Active Directory. I have followed the directions for setting up a new MVC project and changed the authentication to Organizational Accounts, then it asks for an On-Premise Authority. That should be a URL that points to the metadata document. From everything I can find, that means you need to have Active Directory Federation Services setup, which we do not yet. My question is, is there a way to use the Identity framework to connect to Active Directory without ADFS? It seems like this should be a really common situation, but I cannot find anything on it.

If this is possible, do you enter something else in On-Premise authority line, and what would that be?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be adfs, it can be **any** STS that supports passive ws-federation protocol.

You can either use adfs, the thinktecture identity server or even craft your own simple sts that would consist of two pages, a login page and a ws-fed endpoint. Crafting your own sts is not that difficult if you know how. There are tutorials available, I wrote a tutorial by myself once.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/08/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web.html